# PhantomJS don't find elements hidden by 'display:none'

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm having trouble to automate some functional tests using phantomJS and Selenium Web-Driver on Eclipse, perhaps you guys can help me.

I have a product card that shows three elements that are hidden by JavaScript when you perform a hover on it, there are two selects and one button.

It was not finding the selects and I've solved this by adding ' hover' on the div class that enable the animation to show the elements:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('card--').className+=(' hover');");
```

That way I was able to set the model and the quantity on the selects.

But when I try to send the click action on the button, the Selenium returns that the element is not visible and may not be manipulated.

I've tried by setting the display as 'block' on the div the shows these elements, with the following code, but is still not working:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('o-card__add')[0].style['display']='block';");
```

I've already tried by using the JavascriptExecutor to perform a forced click on it using `arguments[0].click` but still didn't worked.

I'm starting to feel hopeless.
Here is the full method code:

```
public SearchResultsPage selectProdModel() {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, GlobalVariables.timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(productCard, 0));
        //Forces the hover on the card
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('card--').className+=(' hover');");
        WebElement prodCard = driver.findElement(productCard);
        //Verify if it has the model selector
        if(prodCard.findElement(productModel).isDisplayed()) {
            select = new Select(prodCard.findElement(productModel));
            List<WebElement> models = select.getOptions();
            for(int x = 1; x < models.size(); x++) {
                if(!models.get(x).getText().contains("Esgotado")) {
                    select.selectByValue(models.get(x).getAttribute("value"));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //From here starts the problem
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('o-card__add')[0].style['display']='block';");
        WebElement cardAdd = prodCard.findElement(By.cssSelector(".o-card__add"));
        cardAdd.findElement(btnAddCart).click();
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Really? No one?

Comment: If you find a solution to this, pls let us know

Comment: My solution until now was to keep using the Chrome Webdriver :/